# I want to go to a new page to see the description from the api in Nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am writing a code in Nuxt js and I have news from an API as cards,  if I click on a card, I want to go to a new page with the full description from the API. How can I make it with Nuxt js?

I have the cards with the data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "Full Description" component for this page, allowing you to access the full description from the API.
and create another component(New.vue).
In this page where you display the cards , you can use a v-for loop to iterate over your card data and create a clickable link for each card that navigates to the full description page.
Here's a basic example of how your News.vue component might look:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
      <div @click="goToFullDescription(card.id)">
        <!-- Display card data here (e.g., card.title, card.image, etc.) -->
        <h2>{{ card.title }}</h2>
        <img :src="card.image" alt="Card Image" />
        <!-- Other card content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [] // Your card data from the API
    };
  },
  methods: {
    goToFullDescription(cardId) {
      // Use Nuxt's programmatic navigation to go to the full description page
      this.$router.push(`/full-description/${cardId}`);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In your FullDescription.vue component, you can retrieve the full description from the API based on the cardId parameter in the route. You can use Nuxt's asyncData or fetch method to fetch the description data based on the cardId and display it on the page.
Here's a basic example of how your FullDescription.vue component might look:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Display the full description data here -->
    <h1>{{ fullDescription.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ fullDescription.description }}</p>
    <!-- Other full description content -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ params }) {
    // Fetch the full description data based on params.cardId
    const cardId = params.cardId;
    // Fetch data from your API using axios or a similar library
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/cards/${cardId}`);

    return {
      fullDescription: response.data // Full description data
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

How should it look in the folder?

Comment: it should look like this in the folder: 
- pages/
  - News.vue
  - FullDescription.vue
- components/
  - Card.vue